# ghci shows type as being concrete

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Exp' a where
  Float' :: (Num a) => Float -> Exp' a
g = Float' 1.2
```

If I type the above code directly into `ghci`, and check `g`'s type, I'd get:

```
GHCI> let g = Float' 1.2
GHCI> :t g
g :: Num a => Exp' a
```

The above is what I expected.

However, when loading a file with the above code, I'd get this instead:

```
GHCI> :load <filename>
GHCI> :t g
g :: Exp' Integer
```

Any idea why the behaviors are different? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. It does. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) which is enabled in source files, but disabled in GHCi.

Basically, the rule is that variable bindings without arguments are always inferred to have a concrete type. In your case the binding `g = Float' 1.2` doesn't have arguments, so it's `Num` constraint will be defaulted to Integer when inferring types.

You can see that the behavior changes if you add a dummy argument:

```
g () = Float' 1.2
```

Or if you just disable the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Comment: Yes, when I added `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to my source file, the result is expected (`g :: Num a => Exp' a`). Thank you very much @Noughtmare !